# Let $X$ be a probability measure. If $f$ is not constant a.e, then there is $\lambda$ s.t $0<\mu(f^{-1}(\lambda,\infty))<1$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a probability measure. If $f$ is not constant a.e, then there is $\lambda$ s.t $0<\mu(f^{-1}(\lambda,\infty))<1$

I found a proof but it is long and I feel like this should be a one liner.

In my proof I assume all such sets have measure either $0$ or $1$. let $A=\{\lambda|\mu(f^{-1}(\lambda,\infty))=1\}$ I prove that $A$ must bounded. Thus $\sup(A)$ exists. If $\sup(A) \in A$ $f=\sup(A)$ a.e which is a contradiction. If it does not there is a monotonic sequence $\lambda_n \to \sup(A)$. Then using continuity of measure we see that a sequence of $1$'s converge to $0$ which is a contradiction.

With all the details it is fairly lengthy. I smell IVT but not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1):

(Assume $f$ is finite valued.)

The point is that "$\mu \circ f^{-1}$" is a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ so it boils down to an exercise about such measures.  There is a certain amount of "boilerplate" or "legalese" making the proof necessarily a few sentences.

Define a Borel measure $\nu$ by $\nu(A) = \mu(f^{-1}(A))$.  This is a probability measure since $\nu(\mathbb{R}) = \mu(f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})) = 1$.  I claim that if $\nu((\lambda,\infty)) \in \{0,1\}$ for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\nu = \delta_{\bar{\lambda}}$ for some $\bar{\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, under this assumption, we can let $\bar{\lambda} = \sup \left\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \, \mid \, \nu((\lambda,\infty)) = 1 \right\}$.  $\bar{\lambda} \in \mathbb{R}$ by continuity of measure.  To see that $\nu = \delta_{\bar{\lambda}}$, observe that, for each $\epsilon > 0$,
\begin{equation*}
\nu([\bar{\lambda} - \epsilon, \bar{\lambda} + \epsilon]) = \nu((\bar{\lambda} - \epsilon,\infty)) - \nu((\bar{\lambda} + \epsilon,\infty)) = 1.
\end{equation*}
Thus, by continuity of measure, $\nu(\{\bar{\lambda}\}) = 1$.

We conclude that $\mu(f^{-1}(\{\bar{\lambda}\})) = \nu(\{\bar{\lambda}\}) = 1$, hence $f \equiv \bar{\lambda}$ ($\mu$-a.e.).